# python twisted equivalent in .Net

Tags: .net, twisted

I am trying to write a socket server in .Net. I just read about [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) and found very interesting.

Is there any equivalent library available for .Net ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/development/policy/writing-standard.html) it looks as though the Socket object now has some basic support for async communication.  I don't know of anything equivalent to Twisted in terms of its polished abstractions though.

[This page](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/sockets/article.php/c7695/) has some examples of using the new async APIs (in c#).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take a look at [Microsoft WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734677.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no equivalent library.  Twisted integrates a huge suite of protocols, both clients and servers, together in one central codebase, along with unified abstractions for things like asynchronous request/response, error handling, authentication and filesystem access from the network.  You can cobble something similar together out of a variety of different .NET libraries, and the built-in support for authentication, but as far as I know you can't get it all in one place.

IronPython is not currently a supported platform for Twisted but there's no reason that it couldn't be; if you are interested in using them together you might want to do some testing and see if Twisted itself could run on .NET.